# How to follow raycaster intersection coordinates on an entity?

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality

I'm trying to use the raycaster to draw on a plane.

I know how to be notified when the raycaster and the plane intersect but after that i don't know how to get updated coordinates of the intersection while the raycaster is moving acrosse the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('raycaster-listen', {
  init: function () {
    this.raycaster = document.querySelector('#myRay');
  },

  tick: function () {
    var intersection = this.raycaster.components.raycaster.getIntersection(this.el);
    if (!intersection) { return; }
    console.log(intersection);
  }
});

<a-entity geometry material raycaster-listen></a-entity>
```

Comment: I will update docs now for this, just realize was not documented

Comment: i' geting this error: "SCRIPT438: SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'getIntersection'" my raycaster is this : <a-entity laser-controls="hand: right" id="rlaser" laser="hand: right"></a-entity>

Comment: Oops, it's `raycaster.components.raycaster.getIntersection`